# How can I illustatrate three parallel, non-consecutive, but dependent processes with BPMN?

Tags: bpmn

We are trying to document a Health Assessment process. An assessment is considered complete when we have received, and committed to a database, the lab results from a blood draw, the biometric data from an examination and the answers from a questionnaire to be completed online OR on paper. The biometrics are recorded the same day as the blood draw. The employee can complete the questionnaire anytime in the process. We have no control over the length of time the lab results take to get back. We do not give the employee an end-date for completing the questionnaire. They can do it before or after the exam.

It sounds like a simpler version of the process described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770299/how-can-i-model-many-parallel-activities-in-bpmn-2-0), but I was hoping someone could point me to an online example; I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it visually. If it matters, I'm using Adonis Community Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a few assumptions here, because your description of your process is not 100% clear to me. However, you might want to model something similar to this:[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The process is not clear to the people directing me to document it either... :|  But that's an issue for another Stack forum. :)  I like how it splits, and correct me if I'm wrong, but the gateway after "inform employee" would allow for the questionnaire to be completed EITHER before OR after the blood draw, correct? Because it's a parallel process, the two are independent of each other.

Comment: Correct: that first gateway means that we continue with the lab activity as well as the employee completing the questionnaire. The lab activity and the employee activity do not have any sequential order. While BPMN speaks of a "parallel gateway", what it actually means is, there is no specific order of the "parallel" activities. Nobody is forced to "start" with anything. Having said that, the "parallel join" right before the end event means we "wait" until both pathes (from lab and employee and the subsequent admin work) are completed. Then we can assume the assessment to be "completed".